# view pdf files and prevent save and print options in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to load my pdf file in a web page. The user should not have the provison to save or print the file. 
the below code opens the pdf file as attachment,
but i want to open it directly in the page.

Please also provide any javascript that can disable the pdf menu bar too..

```
  Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
  Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + old_filename + ".pdf");
  Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/pdf_files/" + old_filename));
  Response.End();
```

Comment: If you're generating PDFs by yourself you can set that permissions **inside the PDF**. Once it has built with no restrictions you can't do anything to prevent the user to print/modify/save your document.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to load my pdf file in a web page. The user should not have the provison to save or print the file.

So you want the user to be able to render the PDF locally (which means the file itself must be transferrable to the local computer) but you don't want the user to be able to save it locally? No, you can't do that. Either you stop the information from leaving your machine, or you don't.

You could potentially render the PDF on the server and show it as an image (which they would, of course, be able to download) - but if you're providing the PDF itself to the client, it's always going to be trivial to save it.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent downloading the pdf file and view it in the web page?

Comment: @AkhilParameswaran: Not unless you perform the rendering on the server, as I say in my answer. Even then, someone would be able to save the rendered image. Heck, *whatever* you do, someone can take a photo of their screen...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can use java script function to stop right click on your web page ( then user do not get save menu by right clicking on pdf/ image) but still they can save page by typing ctrl+s on keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disbale saving function, you could use iframe to show your pdf file.

Also, add "#toolbar=0" at the end of your pdf link for the src parameter.

Take a look:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

======================

For printing function, you could secure your pdf file.

Take a look:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/8.0w/Professional/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7e04.html